# Force WooCommerce to regenerate meta_data for all products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a website with 3000 products that I only update with API. Still, I recently noticed that my products only have a handful of meta_data for each. When I save the product directly from WordPress admin, that product will have almost 50 meta_data, so obviously, saving a product with API does not force WordPress to generate meta_data.

This makes problems with plugins such as ACF that do not show the fields unless I save the product manually.

So, how do I make WordPress do all of these to all the products since it is out of the question to do them manually?

I tried this:

```
wp_update_post(get_post($product_id));
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/

Comment: i don't have problem with editing fields with API

Comment: Does calling the `save()` method on `WC_Product` object generate the meta data successfully? If yes, you can loop through all products and simply run `$product->save()` for each one of them.

Comment: No, I tried it, but it didn't work either only saving it manually works. Thanks

Comment: Try with acf hook - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: I tried this too, but it didn't work